# What callback should be used to handle when app is cleared from ram?

Tags: android, triggers, callback

I want to clear shared preference when I press home button then the app is cleared swipe or simply cleared from device ram. What callback should I use ? (Like OnDestroy, but OnDestroy is not working for me)

Comment: OnDestroy gets called only when the app is killed by the user using the back button. When the app is cleared using swipe, onDestroy isn't called.. However, onPause is called in all scenarios whenever the app loses focus

Comment: there is no such callback.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onPause()` for doing stuff when the activity loses focus (multi-window mode, home button pressed, swiped away, or anything that takes focus away from the activity). The rest aren't guaranteed to be called.

Comment: cant, because when my app start. It automaticaly intent to the login screen if there is no account inside the shared preference. So the onPause is automatically called. But the problem is if I clered

Comment: _"when I press home button then the app is cleared swipe or simply cleared from device ram"_ - `onPause()` certainly works for these situations, but it also runs when the screen goes off.

Comment: well, using onPause is a problem. My app need to implement stay logged in and not stay logged in. If I clear my session when onPause then whenever I intent to new activity then my session is going to be cleared right? What I want is when the device screen is off or the state when we press the home button.